# how to post values to certain url using razor form in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-post, payment-gateway

i am working with Atom Payment Gateway and done with the payment part and now i am working with refund part in the documentation they suggested
i have to use form and action is used as the URL given by Atom for e.g

```
<form action="https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/rfts" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value="197" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="VGVzdEAxMjM=" />
    <input type="hidden" name="refundamt" value="200.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="txndate" value="2019-01-08" />
    <input type="hidden" name="merefundref" value="123" />
    <input type="hidden" name="atomtxnid" value="25631" />
    Submit : <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

but in my project i have to implement this with mvc using razor form i have to use controller to get the info of refundamt, currentdate and merefundref

if i use demo hidden values then i am getting the response

but in my project i have to use controller method to get this values then post to that given url.
in the documentation they have given that the method should compulsory be HttpPost without that the Url will not give expected response.

in my project i have used the razor form with controller method and http POST method then i am going to that method but not able to post the above values to that particular url

Here is my razor form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Refund", FormMethod.Post))
{
     <input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value="197" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="VGVzdEAxMjM=" />
    <input type="text" name="atomtxnid" value="100004487215" />
    <input type="hidden" name="refundamt" value="200.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="txndate" value="2019-01-08" />
    <input type="hidden" name="merefundref" value="25631" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Here is my controller method

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/rfts");
    }
```

In normal Html form i am using action as that given url and passing values with hidden and text field but in my case i want to post values through the controller method to that url please help me with this 'https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/rfts' url

Please suggest me a way to post the above values through controller method to this

Comment: are you passing the values to the url or you are passing values to your controller then to the url?

Answer (score 0):

if you are just gonna pass the values first two null for the controller and action of your project, `@action = ....` is the part for the url you want to post

```
@Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new {@action="https://paynetzuat.atomtech.in/paynetz/rfts"}
    <input type="hidden" name="merchantid" value="197" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="VGVzdEAxMjM=" />
    <input type="text" name="atomtxnid" value="100004487215" />
    <input type="hidden" name="refundamt" value="200.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="txndate" value="2019-01-08" />
    <input type="hidden" name="merefundref" value="25631" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

)
```

but if you want to do something first to the hidden values passed, catch it first in the method in

```
//all of the values you will post is 
//acceptable in string, 
//so i will just use string, but it will depend on you 
//if there is a type you want to use.
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string merchantid, string pwd, string atomxnid, string refundamt, string txndate, string merefundref)
{
    //do something
    //return it to a view as a model
    //do step above with html.hiddenfor(model => model.prop1/prop2);
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: actually i want to go to controller method and then in controller i want to insert the fields and then want to post to the url with this field as hidden fields so the ideal response would be the url showing this hidden parameter in xml response

Comment: @shreyas35 thanks for the info, will edit it after doing some project on my end